# How to use getStaticProps and withRouter next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, server-side-rendering

So I'm trying to fetch from my express api before the page loads so I'm  trying to use getStaticProps but I'm also using withRouter which passes a parameter and getStaticProps does too so I thought it would pass it to the second parameter because the first is withRouters but It just returned an empty object. Thank You!

Here is my code:

```
import { withRouter } from "next/router";
import PrivChatRooms from "../../components/Priv-chat-rooms";
import { socket } from "../index";

const privateChat = withRouter((url, props) => {
    socket.emit("create chat room and joined", {
        roomName: url.router.query.chat_room_name,
        usersInRoom: url.router.query.nickname,
    });
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <div>
            <PrivChatRooms socket={socket} chatRoomName={url.router.query.chat_room_name} />
        </div>
    );
});

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const req = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/privateRooms");
    const data = await req.json();

    return {
        props: { users: data },
    };
}

export default privateChat;
```